# Minkowski geometry definition

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, inertial-frames

The general relativity is based on Minkowski geometry definition with its special properties. The general relativity cant be approved wihout Minkowski geometry definition. Why Minkowski geometry is "True"? I can understand that the general relativity has been approved using measuring of light deviation when passing the sun vicinity, but I want to know in a simple reasoning!!!! that how Albert Einstein accepted the accuracy of Minkowski modelling.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> The general relativity is based on Minkowski geometry

but I suspect most of us would take the opposite view. If you take the Einstein equations and look for solutions where the stress-energy tensor is zero then you find a number of these [vacuum solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_solution_(general_relativity)). These solutions include black holes, along with some very esoteric geometries, but if you look for the solution with the lowest energy you find just one with a zero [ADM mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADM_formalism), and that solution is the Minkowski metric.

The point is that the Minkowski geometry is  prediction of general relativity for a particular stress-energy tensor, so the Minkowski metric exists because the Einstein equations are a good model for spacetime, not the other way around.

This changes your question to ask why general relativity is true, and the answer is that there is no special reason why general relativity **has** to be true. We believe it's true because [it's supported by the experimental evidence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377).

Answer (score 0):

Look around you.  Space appears to be flat, and time appears to be linear.  So locally, spacetime appears to be a flat ${\mathbb R}^4$.

If you start with the twin assumptions of relativity and invariance of the velocity of light, it follows that the laws of physics are invariant under Lorentz transformations.   The Minkowski metric is (by definition!) the unique bilinear form on ${\mathbb R}^4$ that is preserved by  Lorentz transformations.

So asking "Why locally Minkowski?" is equivalent to asking "Why locally Lorentz-invariant?", which in turn is equivalent to "Why relativity and the constancy of the velocity of light?".   The considerations that led Einstein to these postulates have been widely discussed on this site and elsewhere.